# Should we add more specific tags for ME3 questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

ME3 has more than 500+ tags at the moment, and we are starting to get a number of duplicates (including ones I've opened). Should we consider going through old questions to add more tags to them to be more specific so that people searching can better find matches and reduce duplicates?

Potentially tagging with things like [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) or [weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) or similar things.

Comment: Retag them to what?

Comment: @Resorath Adding some more specific tags to it. Things like multiplayer or weapons or something. Maybe retagging is the wrong phrasing. Changed it to "Add tags" instead.

Comment: It's worth remembering that there will always be people who will not search at all before asking a question; some will not even look at the questions that come up as possible matches as they type their questions out. I agree that this is a question worth asking; just know that any solution will only address part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding cross-game tags like [weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) is *not* a good idea. It confuses things, and really, how many people are going to be interested specifically in ME3 questions relating to weapons specifically (and want to filter based on that)? The only extra tags that should need to be added for most questions is platform tags, where appropriate.

Sure, the homepage is a [mass-effect-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3) party at the moment, but so it was for Skyrim, for Starcraft 2, for Minecraft etc. etc. That's just the nature of the game!

Comment: WEAPONS IS NOT A META TAG husdbvfhias dhjsa hjd ashud sja djhas das djbsa dghua sduhv sadjh san d paging @gracenote to explain this further but asjdvasjhd jhsavdjhas dhjas dghjv adhiasbd

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yeah I don't like these being called "Meta tags" at all. [Weapons] seems like [Compilers] would be on SO...problem is it's just of less value on GSE because of the level of domain specific knowledge. It's not a meta tag like [homework]

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz What would you call it then?

Comment: Subtag, and dependent tag have both been tossed around, as has the awkwardly bulky non-game-specific-tag.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz `cross-game` seems appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

The only "bonus" tags that I think are worthwhile are the ones we've already been using:

- [ps3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps3) [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) and [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) when a question is specific to a certain platform
- [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) when talking about the game's multiplayer component

Tags are best when they provide *necessary* context for the question. If the context isn't needed (such as [weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)), it just becomes noise.

Comment: +1 for noise, SE sites are all about high signal/noise

Answer (score 2):

There may be some secondary tags that could be of use, for example [missions-citadel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missions-citadel), [missions-priority](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missions-priority) in the style and intent of tags like [zerg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zerg) but I would be reluctant to see whole scale secondary tagging.

Good titles are better than bad tags ... makes the answer easier to find in search or google anyways, imo.