# Cleanup 2013: It's time for consensus on... the multiplayer tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The multiplayer tag is not a good tag. Here are some previous resources for some "light" reading before we get started:

- [Player Two Press Burninate? Should we keep the [Multiplayer] tag?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5114/52800)
- [The Great Arqade Clean-Up of 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4758/52800)
- [Should we add more specific tags for ME3 questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4200/52800)

I'd rather this be discussed than closed as a duplicate - if it was a duplicate then the consensus from the previous questions would have carried enough weight for them to be actioned.

First things first: Is this a burnination? Picking up from the previous consensus the following was agreed:

> - [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) -  this tag is [scheduled for burnination.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/player-two-press-burninate-should-we-keep-the-multiplayer-tag)
>     **However**, there are a few special caveats:
>
>   1. **DO NOT** remove this tag from any questions which are also tagged as [mass-effect-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3). There will be a request to rename
>        [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) to [mass-effect-3-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-multiplayer) at the end of
>        burnination.
>   2. There are a number of other titles where a hyphenated multiplayer tag makes sense. Use your best judgement, and/or follow
>        the example set by other editors to apply these where needed. For
>        example, [ac-revelation-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ac-revelation-multiplayer) might make sense, though it's
>        borderline. <sup>(CURSE YOU TAG LIMIT!)</sup>

From this it seems like the community agreed to burn the tag through a merge, after cleaning up all of the instances that used the tag.

Is this still how the community feels? Recently we've had the release of Grand Theft Auto 5, which has an associated game mode known as GTA Online. Thus, we have tags [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) and [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online), however in many instances we end up with the [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) tag on there as well. This isn't the only instance of the problem either! A quick glace over [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) shows that it is in use in many other instances:

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)
- [civilization-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5)
- [battlefield-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-3)
- [call-of-duty-black-ops-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops-2)

...and many others. Obviously viewing these, the previous consensus didn't stick.

What is the role of the multiplayer tag?

Are we keeping it?

If so, are we applying any specific use cases?

Are we burning it?

Comment: In many cases, the multiplayer game is inseparable from the singleplayer. (this is definitely the case with [tag:minecraft], anyway). I don't understand why it's used there.

Comment: In those instances, the tags should be edited to remove the multiplayer tag and just use a game tag.

Comment: @Unionhawk - There was a time when Minecraft Singleplayer used a different codebase to Minecraft Multiplayer, and therefore had its own problems and... inconsistencies. Thankfully, that time has passed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### This has been completed.

---

Let's just start enacting the plan that has been agreed upon twice already. This is a big tag to fix, with nearly 400 question, so **we need everyone's help on this one.**

1. Go to the [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) tag.
2. Pick a tag you're familiar with from the Related Tags section
3. Start retagging those questions.

In most cases, all you'll need to do is remove [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer).  If you're unsure, don't do anything. Since [mass-effect-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3) has the most questions, don't edit any of those.  We'll stick with the original plan to rename [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) to [mass-effect-3-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-multiplayer) once all the other instances of [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) are taken care of.

If you see a [closed question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmultiplayer%5D%20closed:yes) (non-dupes) along the way, casting a delete vote is usually the correct thing to do. Especially if it's been closed for a while.  **Use common sense here.**  Also, be sure to fix any other tag problems you see.

For example:

- [modern-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-warfare) doesn't need to be tagged with [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer)
- [modern-warfare-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-warfare-2) doesn't need to be tagged with [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer)
- [modern-warfare-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-warfare-3) doesn't need to be tagged with [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer)
- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) doesn't need to be tagged with [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer)
- [call-of-duty-black-ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-black-ops) doesn't need to be tagged with [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer)

Once we get the related tags taken care of, we should be left with a bunch of questions tagged only [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer).  That will be the true test of the value of this tag.

Comment: Re voting to delete closed questions: the obvious blanket exception would be duplicates, I'd think? Those are useful as redirects.

Comment: Yes, we don't delete dupes.  Just retag those.

Comment: Does me3-multiplayer need the synonyms [matchmaking] and [online]? They've been carried over from [multiplayer]

Comment: @Robotnik [synonyms removed](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7922/52800)

Comment: @kalina I saw, thanks :)